# Are theorems (not axioms) listed as a part of a formal system?

Tags: formal-systems

Are theorems derived from a formal system a part of that formal system? In other words, do we view a formal system as a shorter way of listing all the theorems that flow from such a system?  In other words, can a formal system be viewed as a recipe for generating theorems but no theorems except axioms are included in that recipe?

Comment: A [Formal system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system) is used to infer theorems from axioms according to a set of rules. The [definition of the system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system#Background) includes : symbols, grammar, axioms and inference rules.

Comment: See also the post [Axiom systems and-formal systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408131/axiom-systems-and-formal-systems).

Comment: So simply stated the answer would be: "No, theorems does not count as a part of a formal system". Is that right?

Comment: The "list" of the theorems does not occur as part of the definition : [a *formal system* is a system of axioms equipped with rules of inference, which allow one to generate new theorems.](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/#Out). A formal system is an "abstract machine" to pruduce theorems.