# Definitive references for formal systems

Tags: logic, reference-request, soft-question, big-list, formal-proofs

I would like to compile a list of sources for various formal systems.$^1$ Ideally, I am looking for an explicit statements of *all* rules which apply to each canonical formal system (e.g. dealer's choice of Hilbert proof calculus, sequent calculus, $\lambda$-calculus, etc.) - the more, the merrier.

I ask that these references be "definitive" because I have found that most texts discussing formal systems resort to a very relaxed form of explanation that overlooks particulars of any given formal system in favour of convincing the reader that such-and-such formal system can, *in principle*, prove such-and-such conclusion, and that such-and-such conclusion is true. This does little to help me when I am looking for information about the *system itself* - in fact, it tends to act as an obstacle. Instead of finishing the book, I have to spend days playing six degrees of citation to find some obscure German paper from 1907 detailing the syntax of the system in use. I couldn't even find a  written copy of the axioms of ZFC until a few months ago!$^2$

So, rather than drive myself mad searching in vain for the "SKI-combinator bible," I figured I'd just ask for gratuitous list of user manuals and get as much of it out of the way as possible.

Thusfar, I have two  sources:

*Principia Mathematica* by Whitehead and Russell (which I will probably never consult)

*Metamath: A Computer Language for Mathematical Proofs* by Norman Megill (literally the documentation for a proof checker)

Still, both of these (the latter especially) devote a bit more ink to explaining why the reader should care about the system than I'd like.

---

$^1$ I suppose that I actually mean "various formal systems, proof systems, term rewriting systems, and logics." But I honestly don't see the purpose in distinguishing between these since, at the end of the day, each is just a means of converting sets of strings into other sets of strings.

$^2$ No, the axioms listed on the Wikipedia article on Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory, the Wolfram Mathworld entry for Zermelo-Fraenkel Axioms, and the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy page on Zermelo-Fraenkel Set Theory, are *not* the axioms of ZFC, they are the axioms of a definitional extension of ZFC. Yes, there is a difference.

Comment: I think it would be far more useful to ask about specific problems you have with specific presentations of formal systems rather than make a highly general statement about "most texts discussing formal systems". Certainly, whatever it is that you want of the "list" described in your first paragraph, I don't think anyone is going to compile it for you as an MSE answer.

Comment: See the reference in the answer to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408131/axiom-systems-and-formal-systems)

Comment: Raymond Smullyan's books also good: [Theory of FS](https://books.google.it/books?id=O4wZLfMnd74C&printsec=frontcover) and [Recursion Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=UHzmCwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: For an extended Study Guide to intermediate/advanced textbooks in logic [see here](https://www.logicmatters.net/tyl/)

Comment: _Set theory and the continuum hypothesis_ by Paul Cohen.

Comment: @RobArthan I don't expect anyone to compile the list for me. I expect a few people to make contributions where they can, and to build upon that.